# My 2000 Honda CRV starts fine but dies if pedal is pressed before it warms up completely

Tags: honda, crv

My 2000 Honda CRV starts fine but dies if the gas pedal is pressed before it warms up completely. After starting it and then pressing the gas pedal or putting it in gear, it starts to splutter and dies, then is difficult to restart. If allowed to warm up completely it does not have this problem, and runs fine.

Comment: Are there any codes? This sounds like the Throttle Position Sensor (TPS) to me, but would think a code would pop if there was a problem there.

Comment: It happend to me when the car had 95 octane gas so I solved using 97 octane or using STP inyector cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be surprised if the car is suffering from poor fuel economy.

The most-probable explanation for the observed symptoms is that the fuel trim is rich to begin with, which is further enriched by the fuel management when the engine is started cold. Pressing the gas pedal makes the fuel trim large enough to cause the engine to sputter and stall.

So what could cause this? There isn't enough information provided to be sure, but checklist of things to inspect would include:

- an under-reading MAF sensor
- a "lazy" pre-cat lambda sensor
- intake-side air leaks
- insufficient fuel pressure

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like an O2 sensor. Search for info on o2 sensor diagnostics & 
replacement.

Comment: If this is an O2 problem, what makes it an O2 problem? What should the OP do to fix the issue? Fleshing out your answer will help people solve their issues. As it stands, this "answer" is ripe for deletion due to that lack.